# React/Redux can i use reverse()

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, reverse

i begin with Redux,

can i reverse my state :

```
return {
  ...state,
  articles: [ ...action.payload ].reverse()
};
```

Comment: Yes you can....

Comment: Why are you asking?

Comment: @FelixKling I ask because I start that I do not know if it is the right way

Comment: But there must be something that makes you question whether it's the right way or not. I'm just asking because if we can put that reason into the question, it might be easier to find by/more helpful for others.

Comment: @FelixKling ,I am the question if I mute my array, is that Redux will return an error or no

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are doing the reverse on a `new Array`, you are not mutating the state directly, so I would say it's **fine**